# Pagination not working correctly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

my pagination is not working correctly.when the pagination is clicked it takes time to display the result and when we click the page one after other ,the pages are continuously loaded. why this happens ...Can any one help me with this?????.............

my view.blade.php

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">    
                                  <div class="item active"> <img src="{{ Config::get('constants.site_url') }}public/hotel_images/{{ $rat->image }}" class="img-responsive center-object"/> </div>
                                  @if(!empty($rat->imagestore))
                                    @foreach($rat->imagestore as $image)

                                        <div class="item"> <img src="{{ Config::get('constants.site_url') }}public/uploadStoreImages/{{ $image->store_image }}" class="img-responsive center-object"/> </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <p>{{$rat->restaurant}}</p>
                            <p>Address : {{$rat->address}}  </p>
                            <p>City : {{$rat->city}} </p>
                            <p>Zip : {{$rat->zipcode}}</p>
                            <p>Offer : {{$rat->offer}} </p>
                            <p>Price : $$  </p>
                            <!--<p>Price : {{$rat->price}} </p>-->
                            <p>Link : <a href="{{$rat->url}}">{{$rat->url}}</a> </p>                            
                            <p>{{$rat->description}} </p>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <h3>{{$rat->phone}}</h3>
                            <a href="#" class="special" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_{{$rat->id}}" data_value="{{ $rat->id }}">Special</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

pagination.blade.php page

```
<div class="posts">

@include('front_end/stores/stores1')
</div>


 <script>

     /* var url = window.location.href; 
      var parts = url.split("?");
      var result = parts[parts.length - 1]; */

    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
            if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                getPosts(page);
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function (e) {
            getPosts($(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1]);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    function getPosts(page) {


      var url = window.location.href;   
      var parts = url.split("?");
      var result = parts[parts.length - 1];

      $.ajax({
            url : '?page=' + page ,//'&cat_id={{ $cat_id }}',
         }).done(function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $('.posts').html(data);
            location.hash = page;
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('Posts could not be loaded.');
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Controller.php

```
if($cat_id != 0){
            if($subcat_id == 0){
                $restaurant = Restaurant::leftjoin('cities','restaurant.city','=','cities.id')
                             ->leftjoin('cuisine','restaurant.cuisine','=','cuisine.id')
                             ->where('restaurant.category','=',$cat_id)
                             ->select('*','restaurant.id as id','restaurant.id as rest_id','restaurant.created_at as user_created')->orderBy('restaurant.id','desc')
                             ->paginate(3);
            }else{
                $restaurant = Restaurant::leftjoin('cities','restaurant.city','=','cities.id')
                             ->leftjoin('cuisine','restaurant.cuisine','=','cuisine.id')
                             ->where('restaurant.category','=',$cat_id)
                             ->where('restaurant.subcategory','=',$subcat_id)
                             ->select('*','restaurant.id as id','restaurant.id as rest_id','restaurant.created_at as user_created')->orderBy('restaurant.id','desc')
                             ->paginate(3);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using datatables? https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Comment: i cant use datatables because my client dont need that ... he has provided me a design